# Keep image compressed Java

Tags: java, image, compression, png

I have a server and I want to compress images in it. When I write the image, it goes from 23MB to 650kb and it's okay. But when I'm reading it to send it to my client app, the size is back to 23MB.

```
    public static BufferedImage getProfilePicture(String username) throws IOException {

    File input = new File(profilePicturePath + File.separatorChar + username + ".png");

    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);

    rewriteImage(image);

    return image;


}

public static String getProfilePictureBase64(String username) throws IOException {

    BufferedImage img = getProfilePicture(username);

    final ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(img, "png", os);
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(os.toByteArray());


}
```

So my question is : How can I keep the compressed size to send image to my client ?

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: Edited. But my question is how to send a compressed picture to my client ?

Comment: That 23 Mb, is that the size of the uncompressed image or of its base64 encoded version?

Comment: It's the size of the uncompressed image. When I write all my base64, it's 33Mb.

Comment: 1. What does `rewriteImage(..)` do? I suspect this is where "things" happen. 2. Don't use `ImageIO` to handle files/streams, if you don't plan to edit an image. Most likely you could just have Base64-encoded the byte contents of `input`  directly. Which would have kept the file size as it was. 3. Before Java 9, a PNG written by (the default) `ImageIO` PNG plugin would always write using the maximum compression. Your image is compressed. The file size increase is caused by something else.

Comment: The rewriteImage is just a function to write again the image I read and then see if the file is still compressed. It's really just to test. So you suggest me to read all the file content as a file and not an image and encode this content directly in base64 ?